# Render problems with very large virtual tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am using [this tablescript](https://github.com/danielgindi/jquery.dgtable) to display a virtual table but for some reason after a specific point problems occur.

On **Google Chrome** after the top value (The position value where the row is displayed in the parent div) of  1.677715e+07px (16777150px) is exceed the rows are missing its border-bottom for some reason.
 This happens on the newest version of Chrome (v69).
 On version 68 the rows at this top value and more arent rendert at all.
They are still there, you can see them via the inspect tool on the browser.

Does the number 16777150 has something to do with JavaScript or Google Chrome?

On **Edge browser** something different happens. If the parent div of the virtual table exceed the height of 10737418px, the rendered height of this div will be only as big as its content height
 So if the last row is ending at top 900px, the table will be 900px height too.
 If you scoll further down and the new row is rendert, the div will get bigger too. But in the inspector you can see the right height value in this element and it doesnt change at all.

```
To post this link I need this code..
```

[Here is the Code exampel.](https://pastebin.com/jpuDuChG)

If you want it to test it yourself, the .js and .css are in the github of this tablescript in the example folder.

Maybe this hase something to do with the browsers or JavaScript so I ask this question here.

Comment: If you want someone to test your code don't link to pastebin and if you reference github than post the code in the question. I mean if you delete the repository the code is gone and this question wouldn't make sense for future visitors. Also I doubt someone will download your code from github so just make a JSfiddle or SO code snippet

Comment: I copied it on pastebin because it was to big to post here and the github link is the first link in this post. And the Code is not mine, I only modified the example.html and posted the source on pastebin. And sure I can make a JSfiddle.

Comment: Mhh I cant get it to work on jsfiddle :/ https://jsfiddle.net/p75ex1of/10/ Somehow it doesnt know the table script even it is at resources.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your table is being displayed.
But it's not a good practice to display this much entries at once. Try to use pagination.
Have a look at https://datatables.net/ and try to dynamically load table entries (like pick it up from database or something like this)

Comment: The tablescript does the same too. It renders only like 20 rows at once.

Comment: The Problem with this datatables is for example [this](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/large_js_source.html), just manuel scroll to row 53 and you will see it.

Comment: well, I used datatables some months ago, and loaded thousands of entries without a problem. That's why I recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You had mentioned that tablescript also do the same thing and i see that after many records it display so long empty space without data.
But here, I want to confirm with you that if you use the pagination and display 20 rows at a time then it should work without any issue.
Then why you want to display large number of records?
If you have any issue with 20 rows then try to let us know about that.
We will try to find the solution for it.
Regards
Deepak